# How to design database and make Phone as a table that is in a relationship with another one(Employee)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I am designin a database for Employee Managment System, it has many tables and one of them is Phone because I want Phone to be a table because the employee can have many phone numbers, but in what relation should I assosciate these two , in a way that in the Employee Crud form , I can specify the phone numbers but save them in Phone numbers not in Employee Table..What I am trying to say i associated these two in One-to-many relationship (From Employee to Phone) and i have put an Phone_id as a foreign key at Employee , But how can i access those data from my table , how to mirror those data between those two , maybe that's a weird question but I tried a lot and couldn't find a right solution..
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzDJc.jpg image of the relation..

I have made a one-to-many relationship between those two tables(Employee-Phone) and created a CRUD form for Employee to register a new employee.In the employee table I only have the basic informations for Employee, and phone_id m,that comes as a foreign key from Phone table, and in that crud form i got some fields to add phone1,phone2,phone3 etc..

I excepted that I can save datas from Employee CRUD FORM at both tables employee table and phone table and also generate phone_id in EMPLOYEE Table

Comment: What is your actual question here? Are you asking how to design the tables or help with the code or something completely different?

Comment: `Phone_id as a foreign key at Employee` sounds suspicious to me. Wouldn't one Employee have multiple phones? This is done by having Employee_id as a FK at Phone, not the other way round.

Comment: Hello only with the design of database not the code but just added it to clearify what I am talking about, thanks George and Sean for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refer to Employee table from Phone table. You also may want to specify which phone is primary.

```
Employee (
    ID (primary key)
    Name
)

Phone(
    ID (primary key)
    Employee_ID (foreign key to Employee)
    PhoneNumber
    Primary (boolean)
)
```

Comment: This design allows an employee to have the same phone number several times (with different IDs). It also allows several primary phone number per employee.

Comment: You can add any other constraint you need.

Comment: Sure. But the unthinking practice of slapping unnecessary, meaningsless surrogate id columns on every table means that you are likely to forget these necessary constraints. Not to mention that your table has more columns than it needs to.

Comment: Surrogate keys are very helpful and recommended. you'll know when you get more experience in database design.

Comment: I'll take that patronizing attitude and lack of actual arguments as a sign that further discussion with you is pointless.